# VSFTPD - Change User Home Directory

Tags: centos, ftp, chroot, vsftpd

I need to update a ftp user's home directory. Could I run the `userdel` command then re-add the user without losing the directory the user was attached to? Or is there another way to change the user's directory?

I'm not using a chroot_list either...

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You want to use the `usermod` command. You're going to want to use the `-m` and `-d` directives to modify their home directory and move its contents:

> ```
>   -d, --home HOME_DIR
>        The users new login directory.
>
>        If the -m option is given, the contents of the current home
>        directory will be moved to the new home directory, which is created
>        if it does not already exist.
>
>   -m, --move-home
>        Move the content of the users home directory to the new location.
>
>        This option is only valid in combination with the -d (or --home)
>        option.
> ```